# Unable to import the sample data

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento sampledata:deploy used this command but return the error
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\DependencyResolver\GenericRule.php on line 36. I have increased the php memory limit both in htaccess and php ini but still getting the error